# CV (Curriculum Vitae) Recommender System using Machine Learning, Python, Apache Solr(Back-end), AngularJS (Front-end)

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am very new to Machine Learning. This is my college project. I want to develop web application of CV RECOMMENDER SYSTEM in Python. I have lots of CVs in the format of `.txt`.

My questions are following:

1. What type of learning I can apply? (Supervised/Unsupervised)
2. I have different file in one folder. So Is there need to make a corpus? If there is a need to make a corpus then can I create a corpus?

I am very confused with the flow of the application.

Can please anyone **suggest me the steps** how can I start to develop web application?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, there are many ways, to recommend CVs, but here is what I would do:

I would use TF-IDF or LSI, so an unsupervised learning approach and I would use a corpus.

I would apply word stemming, create a dictionary containing unique word stems of the CVs, create a corpus containing word stem id from dictionary and word stem count for each word stem in each CV, so the document frequencies (DF) for all word stems, then create [TF-IDF (term frequency inverse document frequency)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) model or an [LSI (latent semantic indexing)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) model from dictionary and corpus. Then you have TF-IDF or LSI vectors for all CVs.

For matching and recommending, you apply word stemming to text input you want to match CVs with, calculate the LSI or TF-IDF vector for this input and match it with the most similar CV by using [cosine similarity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) calculation.

[Here](https://github.com/franziska-w/pythonscripts/blob/master/Python-Script%20(2.7)%20for%20LSI%20(Latent%20Semantic%20Indexing)%20Document%20Matching%20(Example).py) and [here](https://github.com/franziska-w/pythonscripts/blob/master/Python-Script%20(2.7)%20for%20TF-IDF%20(Term%20Frequency%20Inverse%20Document%20Frequency)%20Document%20Matching%20(Example).py) you can find short Python code examples for the approach I described using LSI or TF-IDF.

Comment: Thanks for response. The folder contains  different text files of CV.  How to create a corpus of that data? And how can I create a dictionary of the CV? Can you please explain? @Franziska W.

Comment: You can read all CV text files to a dictionary named "files", like described here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-read-mutiple-txt-files-from-folder-in-python. And from this dictionaries values you create a list of training documents, e.g. documents_train = list(files.values()). You can use "documents_train" like in my code examples and proceed with applying word stemming, creating a word stem dictionary from the word stems and creating a corpus from the word stems and the word stem dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and I will ask if I have doubt.